# Android google map myLocationOverlay disappears?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, mylocationoverlay

I try to add myLocationOverlay to the map. It was not there at first, then when I send the gps position from the ddms, then the blue shining dot appear.

However, after awhile, the blue dot disappear and no where to be found. why?

How can I keep the blue dot appearing in the map? thx!!!

Comment: Are you running your app via the emulator or through a device?

Comment: I've experienced this as well (running through the emulator), I think the standard implementation waits for a new fix every X seconds, then discards the old position if there's no new fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460661/customize-my-location-overlay-update-times addresses the issue, yet the code provided crashes the app. Any other thoughts ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: this is probably the cause.

[GPS not update location after close and reopen app on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389811/gps-not-update-location-after-close-and-reopen-app-on-android)