# How can I get a more accurate location?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, mylocationoverlay

I'm trying to get my current location and show it on a map.

Class `com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay.MyLocationOverlay` does most of the work for you.

But it's coming back with a very coarse result that's off by a couple of clicks.

I'm listening for `onAccuracyChanged()` but that never gets called.

How can I get a more accurate location when using `MyLocationOverlay`?

P.S. manifest has:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered my own answer.

The Settings App has a "Location" entry.

Under location, you can individually choose to enable or disable GPS or network use for location finding.  I had GPS (the more accurate choice) disabled.

Thanks,

```
Peter
```

Comment: nevertheless, here is some additional interesting post for you - since GPS only works well outdoors, so you should consider using both gps and network provider: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380444/android-gps-my-location-finding/3380641#3380641 
and 
Fedor's comment on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655