# unable to get current location on SonyEricsson X10i

Tags: android, android-maps

I am using SonyEricsson X10i phone. I have developend an application that just shows the current location of a user. Now the problem is When i turn on my application it just keep searching. It is not showing anything. Even if i try to use built in navigation system it does not work. I have turned on GPS receiver. My firmware version is 1.6 and kernel version is 2.6. I am not sure but i came to know from some resource that 1.6 firmware does not support GPS. Let me know if someone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you indoor or outdoor? GPS
  usually only works well outdoor.
- Do you
  have turned 'network' as a data
  source on in your location settings?
  Allowing triangulation/cell
  towers/wifi networks to get the
  location if GPS/satellite is not
  available.

Comment: i have checked it outdoor and indoor. but not working. I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: done. Problem solved but for built in navigation not for my application. I have to turn on wifi as well GPS satellite receiver to get navigation working but I am not able to get my current location in application which i am trying to build.

Comment: You should post your code and the location manager you're using (are you using both LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER and LocationManager.GPS)? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380444/android-gps-my-location-finding/3380641#3380641